# Find 4th root of matrix with conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having trouble to find a good approach on the following problem.

Find a $4x4$ matrix $A$ such that:
$A≠I$, $A^2≠I$, $A^4=I$

One given solution is:
$\left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}\right]$

I tried to solve this by calculating $I^{\frac{1}{4}}$ but that does not make any sense.

My question is, how do you solve such problems?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) can be useful.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that.

Comment: If $P$ is such that $PAP^{-1}=D+N$, with $D$ diagonal and $N$ with zeros everwhere except for some $1$s on top of the main diagonal, then $I=PIP^{-1}=PA^4P^{-1}=(PAP^{-1})^4=(D+N)^4$. You can expand $(D+N)^4$ and compute what could be in the diagonal and where you could have $1$s in $N$. For any solution of $D,N$ and an arbitrary invertible $P$ you get solutions of $A^4=I$. You get all solutions, actually, and you can also impose the other conditions $A^{k}\neq I$, for $k=1,2$.

Comment: The matrix in the example is obtained for $N=0$ and $P,D$ equal to the matrices $S$ and $J$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%5B%5B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B-1%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%5D)

Comment: A diagonal matrix built up by fourth roots of unity quickly yields appropriate candidates.

Comment: The top left corner of the given solution is a quarter turn rotation matrix and the bottom right corner is the identity. The other two corners are zero. This means it's just a simple rotation matrix imbedded in a larger space. Another example would be to take the identity matrix and move the top row to the bottom. That would create a permutation matrix which meets this criteria as well.

Comment: The easiest way to solve the problem is probably to write down the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $x^4-1$. This gives rise to the permutation matrix for a four-cycle.